# Fixed footer without overflowing content

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm trying to get a fixed footer in my html which I know can be done with position absolute, and setting the bottom. When I do this, when my content gets bigger than the container, it overflows over the footer.

I tried setting a fixed height for my content. This works, but when viewing on other resolutions, these numbers of course wont work anymore.

This is the HTML:

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="top">
</div>
<div class="content>
</div>
<div class="footer>
</div>
</div>
```

This is the SCSS:

```
.container {
    position: absolute;
    min-height: 90vh;
    max-height: 90vh;
    width: 90%;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    margin: auto;
}

.container, .top {
        color: $primary;
        width: 100%;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: auto auto 1fr 250px;
        grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
        border-bottom: 0.1rem solid $contrast;
        padding: 30px;
        align-items: baseline;
        overflow: auto;
}

.container, .content{
        position: relative;
        padding: 30px;
        font-size: 1.2rem;
}


.container, .footer {
        position: absolute;
        bottom:20px;
        width: 100%;
}
```

I just can seem to figure it out. Also tried flex and grid...

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Did you try adding a `z-index` over the footer and changing the position from `absolute` to `fixed` ?

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I did try what you suggested, but the result is the same.

Comment: Is this markup what you're using in you real application or you just came for this question. Because you've missed to en-close the class names `content`, `footer` by the `"` double quotes